# How would you implement an scrollable grid in your iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uikit, view, uiscrollview

I have about 50 images of 50 x 50 pixel size each. I want the user to pick one of them. So first I thought about an UITableView, but that's just not the right thing. It wastes a lot of screen space. Rather than putting all images one below the other, it would be better to show a grid of lets say 6 columns and n rows.

I would use an UIScrollView and fill it up with UIView objects which I automatically arrange so that they appear like a grid. Is that the way to go? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing something very similar in my app- an NxN grid with an image underneath, and another subview on top to draw the "lines", all owned by a UIScrollView.  I recommend having a separate view to draw the images, something like:

```
-(void) drawRect(CGRect rect) {
    CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [yourImage drawRect: smallerRect];
    // repeat as needed to draw the grid
 }
```

Another poster mentioned that you won't be able to get touch events if your view is owned by a UIScrollView- this is simply not true.  I have it working.  You might need to set the following though:

```
[yourScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES]
[yourGridView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [three20 library](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) has a class that does this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've downloaded it, but XCoede doesn't allow me to launch it for some reason. I can only build, but not "go". Interesting though.

Answer (score 1):

A table view doesn't necessarily imply showing one image per row, as you suggest.  Table cells can be customized, and a cell subclass with six 50x50 UIImageViews would be pretty simple.  It's maybe less flexible than a scroll view but if six images per row is your goal then a table view is the quickest way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

three20 is horrible,ive used it, i dont recommend it... displaying a grid is easy...

```
    - (void) reloadGridView
    {

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 54, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight8)];
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        divisor = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < [self.photosArray count]; i++) {

            int buttonTag = divisor;

            UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self thumbPathAtIndex:i]];
            //********* CREATE A BUTTON HERE **********
            //********* use the thumb as its backgroundImage *******


            if(divisor%4==0){
                y+=70; 
                x = 10;

            }else{
               x += 70;
            }

            divisor++;
        }
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewWidth, ([self.photosArray count]%4 == 0) ? y : y+100)];

}
```

and if you want 6 images when in landscape - setup a BOOL for isLandscape

```
if (isLandscape) {
    //change the divisor to change @ 6 instead of 4
}
```

if you need a more advanced gridView check out AQGridView (Google it)